# jQuery Validate: Form is Being Validated Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that I am using jQuery Validate to validate the form. I ran into an issue. The form is being validated twice. My variable 'isValid' is logged to the console twice after

**The button that triggered the validation is a type button**

```html
<button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" vclass="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

**Below is the JavaScript that has the rules and messages to be displayed to the user. It also include the click event for the button.**

```
$(function () {
$("#createUser").validate({
    rules: {
        FirstName: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            minlength : 2
        },
        zipCode: {
            required: true,
            maxlength : 5
        },
        Telephone: {
            required: function (element) {
                return $('#options option:selected').val() != "1";
            },
            maxlength : 12
        },
        options: {
        required: true,
        notEqual: "1"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        FirstName: "Please specify your first name",
        email: {
            required: "This email field is required.",
            minlength : "email had to have a min length of 2."
        },
        zipCode: {
            required: "Zip code is a required field.",
            maxlength : "zip code cannot be more than 5 characters."
        },
        Telephone: {
            required : "Telephone is a required field.",
            maxlength : "Phone number has to have a max length of 12 characters."
        },
        options: {
            required: "Option is a required field",
            notEqual: "Select a different option"
        }
    }
  });

jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
}, "Please specify a different (non-default) value");


  $('#submit').on('click', function () {
     isValid = $('#createUser').valid();
     console.log(isValid);
  });
});
```

Most of the issues that I've found related to forms being validated twice have to do with having type submit instead button. Also, I a m not calling submit anywhere in my JavaScript file. What am I missing here?

Comment: My guess is that the action is being bound twice.Reproduce it in a fiddle and I'll give you more

Comment: if the rules are in separate js , make sure the script is not referenced twice

Comment: @REDEVI_ that was the issue. I include the folder in my bundle. Then, I added a reference to the JavaScript file forgetting that the folder is also included in my bundle. You can change your comment to an answer, and I'll mark it as resolved.

Comment: Ok i have done so .. thanks ..

Comment: I was banging my head against the same topical issue today.  Proven by `console.log()` print outs, the form wasn't firing twice, but the validator rules were being executed twice -- neither of which was properly halting the submission. I don't know if specific form elements were contributing factors and I am not able to create a [mcve], but in the end I was able to eliminate the double-execution issue and properly validate by extracting the `required: function () { ... }` rule out of the `validate()` declaration using the `addMethod()` method. Then I just wrote `myFieldName: {myMethod: true}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the rules are in separate js , make sure the script is not referenced twice ,